# Logarithmic vector-valued modular functions and quasimodular forms with misleading modular weights

Tags: modular-forms, vertex-algebras, quasimodular-forms

I have a somewhat imprecise question about functions with reasonably nice modular transformations that don't seem to fit nicely into what I understand of the plain vanilla theory of modular and quasimodular functions/forms. In everything below, I have in mind modularity with respect to the full modular group $\Gamma$.

I will use two examples to exemplify the phenomenon of interest.

**Example 1**

This example appears in section 7 of *Arakawa, Tomoyuki; Kawasetsu, Kazuya*, [**Quasi-lisse vertex algebras and modular linear differential equations**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-030-02191-7_2),  [ZBL07065394](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:07065394).

Consider the following function on the upper half plane $\tau\in\mathbb{H}$,
$$
f(\tau) = \frac{E_4'(\tau)}{240\eta(\tau)^{10}} = \frac{E_2(\tau)E_4(\tau)-E_6(\tau)}{720\eta(\tau)^{10}}~.
$$
Here the derivative incorporates a conventional factor of $2\pi i$ and the equality follows from one of Ramanujan's identities. A superficial inspection (comparing modular transformations of the numerator and denominator) suggests that this object might deserve to be thought of as a kind of quasi-modular function of weight one. However, it turns out that this can also be thought of as a component of a two-dimensional vector-valued logarithmic modular function of weight **zero**. This can be understood from the fact that this function arises as a solution of an appropriate second order linear modular differential equation (as in the reference) or by direct computation.

**Example 2**

Consider the relatively simple function on the upper half plane
$$
g(\tau) = \eta(\tau)^2(1-E_2(\tau))~.
$$
Unlike the previous example, here naively I would not want to assign any definite modular weight to this function since it is a mixture of terms that I normally think of as having weight one and three, respectively. Nevertheless, like in the previous example, this is actually a component of a weight-zero, logarithmic, vector-valued modular function (this time the vector is six dimensional, as can again be seen by direct computation but this also arises as the solution of a sixth order linear modular differential equation).

**Question**

I'm wondering if this is a normal or understood phenomenon. Is there a theory of, especially, the second type of example, where functions that look roughly like mixed-weight quasimodular functions built from Eisenstein series can be repurposed as logarithmic vector-valued functions or forms of a fixed weight? Is this interesting? I have encountered large classes of similar objects arising in the setting of certain vertex operator algebras.